# How do I set an xib as the first page in my app in xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xib

I am trying to set an xib file as the first screen in my app in the Xamarin IDE. How do I do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Info.plist it is "Main Interface" under the Application tab, and you should have a dropdown choice of XIBs from your project. In the Source tab, it is also listed, under "Main storyboard file base name". You may have to reload Info.plist after adding .xibs and .storyboards before they show up in the dropdown.

Comment: I tried this but it just goes straight to a black screen, any idea how to fix this?

Comment: What kind of view hierarchy is in your .xib? If there are multiple views and want to select a specific one to be the first, make sure you select the view controller and check "Is initial view controller". This should also automatically uncheck any other view, but you might want to double check the default view controller in the original project-generated .storyboard file is now unchecked.

Comment: its just a single view in my .xib

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can chose it at info.plist